# Applescript : Safari : open a URL in tab 2 without changing the tab

Tags: safari, tabs, applescript

I wonder is that possible to set a new URL in tab 2, while using tab 3, and not focusing on tab 2?

also can we move a tab without focusing ? (moving tab 2 to tab 1 for example and keep displaying tab 3?)

This is my code to set the tab, but this will focus to this table

```
    tell application "Safari" to set the URL of the front document to 
tell window 1 of application "Safari" to set current tab to tab 2
```

"https://URL.com" & ## serialNumber & "/edit/definition"

for moving the table I using this code

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell front window
        move last tab to before tab 2
    end tell
end tell
```

but the tab is focusing, and also, it's seems to reload the URL each time so I have to add a annoying delay otherwise the tab will be blank

Answer (score 0):

Founds it !
tell application "Safari" to set the URL of tab 2 of window 1 to "https://"